# How do Realm add existing user data to the mobile platform?

Tags: ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am currently using Realm as an offline database in the iOS app.
 if I were to add support for Realm mobile platform, will it automatically grab all the Realm user data and migrate it to the cloud?
 Or 
is there some code that is needed to move the data to the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm Mobile Platform is not a cloud service but consists of Realm Object Server, a server application you can run on your own (supports various flavors of Linux) and Realm Mobile Database. If you are already using Realm Mobile Database in your app today, you cannot just upgrade and expect those Realms to sync with Realm Object server. Instead you much create synchronized Realms through the new API and copy data from the existing Realm into the synchronized Realm.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. What I do not understand is that my existing objects are already tied to the local realm database. So how do I efficiently move the objects to the synchronized Realm? oldobjectList = oldrealm.objects(MyObject.self), create synchronized realm, and for each oldobjectList, add to new realm?

Comment: Yeah right now you have to iterate over and add them. The reason that you cannot just convert a standalone Realm to be synchronized is that the transaction history is pruned already and that transaction log now needs to be recreated since this is ultimately what is being synced.